# Why isn't this while loop condition stopping the loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

```
System.out.println("Please enter your grades: ");    

while(scanner.nextInt() != -1){
            numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
```

I have a while-loop which is supposed to stop once a "-1" is entered by the user. Instead, a "-1" is inserted into my arraylist before being recognized. I would like to understand why the loop doesn't stop immediately upon detecting a "-1."

Comment: Each iteration of the loop consumes 2 numbers from the user. The odd numbers (1st, 3rd, 5th, ...) are checked for `-1` and are otherwise ignored (thrown away), and the even numbers (2nd, 4th, 6th, ...) are added to the list. If user enters `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1, 8, 9, -1`, the values `2, 4, 6, -1, 9` are added to the list.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `nextInt` twice, and it returns a new int each time. Try this:

```
while(true){
    int val = scanner.nextInt();
    if (val == -1) {
        break;
    }
    numbers.add(val);
}
```

Comment: I saw others mentioned that I've called it twice. I didn't know that just having scanner.nextInt() within a condition statement would count as a call.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You are typing input twice at each loop because `scanner.nextInt()` is called at two places in the while loop. Just call it one time and save typed value at each round. Below code does exactly what you want:

```
int nextInt;
while((nextInt = scanner.nextInt())!= -1){
    numbers.add(nextInt);
}
```